# How do I declare a module's root export in a Flow interface declaration?

Tags: flowtype

In a Flowtype interface declaration file, how do I declare a module's `module.exports`?

Say, for example, I am using Express:

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
```

Answer (score 4):

The current syntax for this is

```
declare module express {
    declare type Express { ...#use(), #post(), #get(), etc... }
    declare var exports: () => Express
}
```

You can also use `declare function exports(): Express`, or use any other type you want, for example:

```
declare module moduleThatExportsNumber {
    declare var exports: number
}
```

In the future this Common JS-based syntax may be replaced by something that reflects the semantics of ES6 modules.

In `.js.flow` files inside your own library, you can do:

```
declare function createExpress(): Express;
declare module.exports: typeof createExpress;
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like this is changing as the `var exports` syntax is being deprecated

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1806

Interesting that now you can declare a default exported module alongside named exports

A an example for Node's EventEmitter looks like:

```
declare module "events" {
  declare class EventEmitter {
    static EventEmitter: typeof EventEmitter;

    addListener(event: string, listener: Function): events$EventEmitter;
    emit(event: string, ...args:Array<any>): boolean;
    // additional methods ...
  }

  declare export var EventEmitter: typeof EventEmitter
  declare export default typeof EventEmitter
}
```